# Capture HTTP Status 300 for redirect download links

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I'm developing a Chrome Extension to download links on a webpage.
I came across some links there were not a direct download, for example like this one http://downloads.sourceforge.net/sevenzip/7z920-x64.msi

When I trace the link on fiddler, I'm getting **HTTP Status 302** (which is a redirect). So I'm trying to test the link before downloading using XMLHTTPRequest, but I can't retrieve status **302**, XMLHTTPRequest is only retrieving the file status which is **200**?

Is there a trick around this to make it stop at 302 or perhaps a different alternative to AJAX calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible with the use of the [`chrome.webRequest`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html) api. `302`'s and the like are normally handled silently by the browser, but you can use this method to stop them or make them more visible to your code.

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function(details){
    var redirUrl;
    details.responseHeaders.forEach(function(v,i,a){
      if(v.name == "Location"){
       redirUrl = v.value;
       details.responseHeaders.splice(i,1);  //Kill the redirect
      }
    });
    if(redirUrl)
      details.responseHeaders.push({name:"redirUrl",value:redirUrl});
    return {responseHeaders:details.responseHeaders}; 
},
{urls: ["http://*/*"],tabId:-1},["responseHeaders","blocking"]);
```

I specified a `tabId` of -1, which means it should only work for requests not coming from a tab, i.e. a background page. This will silently prevent the redirect while allowing you access to both the `302` status and the url to redirect to.

Comment: Is there any such API for Chrome Apps? The documentation does't mention anything except the usual XHR object. (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index)

Comment: @Osiris Not that I know of. I have little to no experience with apps, but one of these links might be what you are looking for: [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-apps/Wvq2zNQJQ-Y) or [WebRequestEventInteface](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#type-WebRequestEventInteface)